# C++20: difference between [[likely]], [[unlikely]] and __builtin_expect?

Tags: c++, c++20, branch-prediction

Preliminary information: according to the recent [ISO C++ Committee Trip Report](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/854mu9/2018_jacksonville_iso_c_committee_reddit_trip/), the `[[ likely ]]` and `[[ unlikely ]]` attributes for conditional branching will be added in `C++20` and is available in the newest version of GNU GCC (you can play with it on the online compiler [wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/)).

---

**Question:** Is the following construction

```cpp
if (cond) [[ likely ]] { ... }
```

equivalent to the following one?

```cpp
if (__builtin_expect(bool(cond), 1)) { ... }
```

Are there any performance difference or implementation nuances between different compilers that one should be aware of in order to use it effectively?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is the following construction equivalent to the following one?

In intention, yes.

---

> Are there any performance difference or implementation nuances accross compilers that one should be aware of in order to use it effectively?

As you can see from [P0479](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0479r5.html), there is no mandatory wording requirement on the behavior of these attributes. Their behavior is mentioned as part of a non-normative note, which implementations are *encouraged* but not *forced* to follow.

The only way to answer this question is to check the manual of your compiler.

Comment: I'd add that the __builtin* is a compiler intrinsic while [[ likely ]] is going to be a language standard, if this is not too obvious already.